# Calling characters from a string In JS

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to grab a 9 character string from a title, the start of the list is always "BC-" and then it is always six digits following, so for instance a complete thing would look like - "BC-004352" my problem is that I can grab everything after the "BC-" however if there is something after that like "Words Words BC-004352 Words words" it then grabs the "BC-004352 Words Words". This will mess up my program, so is their any way of only capturing the "BC-004352"?   How could I then make the script self executable as at the moment it is running of a button and that isn't helpful

```
<!--BC-Check six digit-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function bc_check() {
    var str = "FUCKCKCKKC  BC-040300 Has broken";
    var res = str.substring(str.indexOf("BC-") + 0);
    document.getElementById("recognize").innerHTML = res;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: RegularExpressions

Comment: `var res = str.substring(str.indexOf("BC-"), str.indexOf("BC-") + 9);`

Comment: Amazing Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do this with Regular Expressions:

```
const testString = "FCKCKCKKC  BC-040300 Has broken";
const regex = /.*?BC-(\d+).*?/; //Capture any number of digits following BC-
const matches = testString.match(regex); //Get the match collection

console.log(matches[1]); //Match collection index 1 holds your number
```

Answer (score 0):

substring has a second parameter for indexEnd. It doesn't include the character at that index so you'll have to add one to get all of the chars you want. So in this case you'll want to add 10 to the index of "BC-".